# Missin required position argument

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function and this snippet of code resulting in an error. How can I fix this?

```
test = db()
user = "test"
pw = "test"
db.register(user, pw)

def register(self, user, password):
    """
    Register user to database
    """
    hashe = sha256_crypt.encrypt(password)
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) values('%s', '%s')" % (user, hashe)
    self.cur.execute(sql)
    self.conn.commit()
```

> TypeError: register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Comment: It looks like you've defined `register` as a module-level function rather than a method of your `db` class.

Comment: I'm not really sure I know the difference, how would I go about defining it as a method of my class instead of a module, like you said I have?